Exploring Non-Rotational Artificial Gravity: Can Geometric Energy Fields Create Gravity-Like Effects?
I’ve been thinking a lot lately about ways to simulate artificial gravity in space without relying on rotational systems (like spinning habitats or stations). I'm curious if it's possible to create gravity-like effects using advanced field manipulation or other forms of energy interaction within a confined space, such as a spacecraft or space station.
Areas of Curiosity:
Electromagnetic Fields and Force Generation: Could electromagnetic fields be manipulated in such a way as to simulate the pull of gravity? Specifically, how feasible would it be to create a force field that generates a downward pull on objects or people, mimicking the sensation of gravity? Would the interaction of magnetic fields or energy fields in certain configurations be capable of producing a uniform force throughout a station?
Energy Concentration and Inertial Effects: Could energy fields be concentrated and directed to create inertial effects that simulate gravity in microgravity environments? For example, could an arrangement of high-energy fields (without necessarily using mass) create a force that pulls objects downward in a manner similar to how gravity works?
Geometric Configurations of Field Systems: If multiple energy or field generators were placed in a geometric configuration (e.g., hexagonal or cubic arrangements), could the resulting interaction of fields create a stable zone of force? Could such a configuration be used to influence inertia or create a field that applies a gravitational-like pull on everything inside that zone?
Alternative to Centripetal Force: Given that traditional methods for simulating gravity involve centripetal force through spinning stations, could there be a way to generate a constant downward force without rotation? If so, what types of field manipulation or energy interactions would be required, and what are the challenges in making this practical?
Why I’m Asking: I'm exploring whether field effects or energy manipulation could be a practical solution for long-duration space missions or space stations that need to provide a gravity-like environment for their crew. I understand that creating true gravity requires mass, but could fields or forces be engineered to simulate the experience of gravity?
I would appreciate any thoughts on the theoretical frameworks, experiments, or concepts that are relevant to this idea. Are there existing technologies or scientific principles that could point toward a viable solution for artificial gravity using energy manipulation?
Looking forward to hearing your insights!

I suggest editing your post to ask one question rather than eleven. Otherwise, you risk having your post closed for lacking focus.

Basically none of what you propose is feasible.

I understand that creating true gravity requires mass. The gravity caused by elecromagnetic fields is just as real as the gravity caused by mass. It’s just negligibly small.

You can make someone's hair stand up using static electricity. But if you tried to lift the whole person, it would be rather dangerous...

In general relativity the spacetime curvature, and hence the gravitational field, is proportional to an object called the stress-energy tensor, and in most cases the only significant term in this tensor is the mass/energy density $T_{00}$. However a key difference from Newtonian gravity is that matter density and energy density are equivalent, using Einstein's famous equation $E=mc^2$. So energy stored in fields like electromagnetic fields can create a gravitational field just as matter can.
The problem is that matter density and energy density are equivalent. To create a gravitational field as strong as Earth's you need a mass as big as the Earth, which is pretty big, and to create the field using energy you need to multiply this mass by $c^2$ making it eighteen orders of magnitude bigger!
I would guess you are thinking there might be some clever trick you can play with energy to create a $1\mathrm{g}$ gravitational field, but unfortunately there isn't. If you cannot create your gravitational field with matter then you cannot create it using some form of stored energy either.
